# Convert an Async method to use Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Suppose I have the following method signature for an Async method:

```
public IAsyncResult MyAsyncMethod(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object state);
```

And, therefore, I use the following code to call it and assign it a `state` object and a callback:

```cs
public class test
{
    // Private class to hold / pass-through data used by Async operations
    private class StateData
    {
        //... Whatever properties I'll need passed to my callback ...
    }

    public void RunOnSeparateThread()
    {
        StateData stateData = new StateData { ... };
        MyAsyncMethod(m_asyncCallback, stateData);
    }

    private AsyncCallback m_asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(AsyncComplete);
    private static void AsyncComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    { 
        // Whatever stuff needs to be done after completion of Async method
        // using data returned in the stateData object
    }
}
```

---

I'm looking to do the same thing using Task Parallel Library and am not certain how to do it. What would be the correct code to achieve the same result, being:

1. Run `MyAsyncMethod` on a separate thread
2. On completion have a `state` object returned with it passed to the next method - In this case `AsyncComplete`

Or is there a better way to accomplish the same result?

Also, although this is written in C#, I'm equally comfortable in VB and C#, so any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you and hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: This should help you get started: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism

Comment: Thanks so much, @JoshL., looks like a very useful link - Looking into it now.

Comment: Maybe [this on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) is also good.

Comment: @JohnBustos Yeah, helped me a lot for sure and it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I have the following method signature for an Async method:
>
> ```
> public IAsyncResult MyAsyncMethod(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, object state);
> ```

I would expect the return value to be `Task<T>` (`IAsyncResult` is normally returned from the `BeginXYZ` when there is a matching `EndXYZ` in the original .NET async pattern), and not taking a callback. (As presented it seems to be a bit of one pattern and a bit of another.)

If my expectation is right then, just call the method and use the retuned `Task<T>`.

If it is really a `IAsyncResult` then `TaskFactory` has a helper method: `FromAsync` which amongst its many overloads can take an `IAsyncResult` and an `Action<IAsyncResult>`.

So your code becomes:

```
var ia = MyAsyncMethod(() => {}, null);
var t = Task.Factory.FromAsync(ia, x => { 
    // called with ia from MyAsyncMethod on completion.
    //  Can close over any state
});

// ...
var result = (TypeofResult)t.Result;
```

Comment: `t.Result` would block. I'd advise to `await t` instead, avoiding potential deadlocks as well.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What about for .Net Frameworks below 4.5? Since I don't think await is available before then.

Comment: @Josh If you're on .NET 4.0 and use VS2012 and above, you have the Bcl.Async library via NuGet. If you're on .NET 4.0 and VS2010, you can use `Task.ContinueWith` to access the completed task.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Indeed, but I've assumed that, as the Q asks about using TPL, this is covered in the ellipses because if there isn't something else to be done concurrently then why use TPL?

Comment: This question isn't about parallelism, it's about concurrency and how to convert the APM pattern to the TAP. He can use `FromAsync` because it provides exactly what he needs to do, transform the former to the latter.